# How can I make the h2 in this email optin form in div responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a landing page that I'm creating in Elegant Themes' Divi theme. Here's [the link](http://8f7.588.mwp.accessdomain.com/38-2/) to it. The optin form is mostly responsive. Except, when viewing the form on a smart phone or tablet, the h2 that says "Join today!" is left adjusted when I'd actually like it to be in the center of the screen.

How can I change the h2 using CSS to center it above the optin form when viewing the page on a smart phone or table. I tried to fix the issue for the smart phone view with the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) .et_pb_newsletter { h2 {
text-align: center;
align: center;
}
}
```

But, it's not having the desired effect. I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just set `width: 100%` on parent element. So, `et_pb_newsletter_description { width: 100%}`. Problem is, in big viewports width is set to auto.

Comment: Please always post *all* the relevant code including HTML and CSS so that we can see what you are seeing and provide you with a complete working solution.

Comment: @Walt just updated the CSS with your code and it still doesn't work. On my mobile and when I resize desktop browser the "Joint today" is still left adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `.et_pb_newsletter_description` you have `float` set to left. Set it to `none` or remove the float entirely. You should be able to do this inside of custom css.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I use a media query. Here's what I have and it still produces the same result:    `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)  .et_pb_newsletter_description {
float: none;}`. If I just put `.et_pb_newsletter_description { float: none;}` it looks good on all screens except the desktop. Also, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Walt trying now.

Comment: By the way, you asking about top one or bottom? Because while your top signup looks good, bottom still needs work. Also, do you use developer tools in a browser, if my solution also won't work, there are 2 ways you could do: 1) set !important to override those theme styles or just go in divi builder and set id to a desired div.

Comment: @Walt As soon as I fix the top form I'll use the same solution for the bottom form.

Comment: Nope, you can't use same solution for bottom forms, just set id's for both form and those will override default styles for you.

Comment: @Walt I think the issue is I have this CSS for the desktop version `display: inline-block;
width: auto;
margin-top: 17px;` but I need the CSS you suggested for the mobile and tablet versions. When I get rid of `width: auto` and replace it with `width: 100%` the site looks good on everything but the desktop version.

Comment: @user1483441, you should modify only viewports less than 480px. Did you make the media query right?

Comment: @Walt Here's the CSS with the media query: `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.et_pb_newsletter_description {
width: 100%;
}
}`

Comment: @user1483441, try to take more classes like that: `.et_pb_newsletter .et_pb_newsletter_description` if it won't work, just set `width: 100%!important`, which is a bad practice, but when there are no better solutions, that's a way to go.

Comment: It looks like everything in `.et_pb_newsletter_description` has a class or id except the `h2`. Can you give it a class that's similar to the name inputs? Then maybe the media query will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);

If this is not working at least you can put the `<h2>` tag inside a `<center>` tag.

Comment: Tried that CSS and it still doesn't work. Unfortunately, one of the limits of the theme is that I can't put the <h2> tag inside a <center? tag. Thanks so much though!

Comment: @user1483441, first of all....never modify a theme, make a child theme first.  Second, you can do a lot of modification from a dashboard, in your Divi builder.